# RNN Wix > Task :react-native-navigation:compileReactNative68DebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

So i opened up my project today, ready to export and compile an Android build.

I ran: react-native run-android and ./gradlew bundleRelease" as i always does, but now it errors and fails every time. It's still working on iOS, and no changes have been made to the android part.

Error:

> Task :react-native-navigation:compileReactNative68DebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/Github/YourProjectName/node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/android/app/src/reactNative68/java/com/reactnativenavigation/react/NavigationReactNativeHost.java: error: cannot find symbol
> .setUIImplementationProvider(getUIImplementationProvider())

Anyone know how i can fix this? Been trying literally all answers on SO and GitHub (their repo)

Using Kotlin 1.6 (tried with 1.4.31 also)
RN: 0.68.2

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit (solution)
Add the following in your android/build.gradle file

```
exclusiveContent {
           // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
           // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
           // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
           // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }
```

It's all related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210 and this https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/7630

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing an issue with the android build today as well. Though with a different error message but I suspect you are experiencing the same core problem.

First I noticed that the react-native version resolved for android was incorrect. To see if it's the case also for you navigate to the `android` folder in your project in the terminal (`cd android`) and then run a command to generate a dependency tree: `./gradlew app:dependencies > dep.txt`. Then in the file `dep.txt` search for `react-native:`. If the version of react native doesn't match the version you are using (0.68.2) then add the following to your top-level `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
+       exclusiveContent {
+           // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
+           // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
+           // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
+           // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
+           filter {
+               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
+           }
+           forRepository {
+               maven {
+                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
+               }
+           }
+       }
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can find more details about the issue here
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Comment: Following the link and updating RN fixed it for me. I'm on RN 0.70.4, and updating to 0.70.5 solved the issue.